# How to write a while loop in MarkLogic XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is there any recognized idiom for writing the equivalent of a while loop in MarkLogic XQuery? I know that I could write a tail-recursive routine, but MarkLogic XQuery does not optimize tail-recursion and I'm getting a stack overflow (I have to go around my loop ~20000 times).

*Editorial note: as of MarkLogic 6, tail recursion is optimized in MarkLogic.*

Comment: I think you'd better rethink your logic. What are you trying to achieve? There are probably much better ways of doing what you try. Iterating 20k times doesn't sound the way to go..

Comment: I'm writing a recursive descent parser for converting a string to XML, but actually I'm also interested in any generic idioms, maybe using some MarkLogic extensions.

Comment: you can save yourself writing a parser if you have a grammar. Submit it to this REx parser, and select XQuery output: http://www.bottlecaps.de/rex/

Comment: @grtjn Writing the parser isn't difficult, its a very simple grammar. The problem is the recursive code produced. I'll look at REx but if it outputs conventional recursive code I'm no better off than before.

Comment: @john: I wrote a generic LR-1 parser in XSLT 2.0 years ago. Do have a look -- it may give you some ideas: http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-lrParse.xsl?revision=1.7&view=markup

Comment: MarkLogic 6 supports tail call optimization - maybe you can try that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is the usual way. Another is to use a FLWOR with a `try-catch` and throw an exception with a known code to exit early.

```
try {
  for $x in 1 to count($tokens)
  return tok($x) }
catch ($ex) {
  if ($x/error:code eq 'BREAK') then ()
  else xdmp:rethrow() }
```

The `tok` function would call `error((), 'BREAK')` to exit the parent FLWOR expression. If needed you could multiply the token count by some factor, or use an arbitrary large number.

https://github.com/robwhitby/xray/blob/coverage/src/coverage.xqy has a more complex example, in the `cover:actual-via-debug` function.

Comment: MarkLogic 6 supports XQuery 3.0 try/catch, which allows you to retrieve an arbitrary argument value passed to the fn:error() function when it's called. In this way you can terminate the loop early, and still return a value.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way in XQuery is by using a FLWOR expression. How to write this highly depends on your loop and data as it is not an excact mappoing to a while loop known from other languages.

So what you can do is e.g.

```
let $c := doc('my.doc')/root/get-all-my-elements-using-xpath
return process-result($c)
```

Please be more specific what you actually want to do if you need further advice.

Comment: Thanks but I'm thinking of the cases where you don't have a sequence which you can iterate over. Obviously if I had such a sequence I would use a FLOWR expression.